# Ansible, search key in Dictionaries and compare with variable

Tags: ansible

i need to automate the installation of a docker plugin using ansible.

I’m going to run the playbook using a console variable

```yaml
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "SERVER=new" example.yaml
```

Here the playbook

```yaml
---
- name: "install plugin"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   servers:
    new:
     url: "url-new"
    old:
     url: "url-old"
  tasks:
  - name: "Debug"
    shell: docker install pluginame HOST='{{ dict:new:url:url-new }}' USER='john' PASS='john'
    when: '{{ SERVER }}' in dict
  - name: "Debug"
    shell: docker install pluginame HOST='{{ dict:new:url:url-new }}' 
    when: '{{ SERVER }}' in dict
```

I cannot understand how to compare the SERVER console variable with the url key within each array and I also need to add a conditional in each task to run it if the url key matches the value of the SERVER variable.

Any Helps?

Regards,

Comment: (a) Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74707194/edit) and fix the formatting, it's not hard and matters a lot with yaml (b) you have `-e SERVER=` but haven't referenced that variable anywhere in your question; are you doing that for real, or it's an artifact of a malformed question?

Comment: @mdaniel I have reformulated my request, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a jinja2 condition to get you the url according to the value of the variable `SERVER`.

```yaml
- name: "install plugin"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    new:
      url: newurl
    old:
      url: oldurl
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: docker install pluginame HOST='{% if SERVER=="new" %}{{ new.url }}{% elif SERVER=="old" %}{{ old.url }}{% endif %}'
```